# Falling back if accurate HTML 5 geolocation takes too long

Tags: android, html, geolocation

I'm working on a website that requires the user's location. I'm currently calling getCurrentPosition with enableHighAccuracy set, which uses the GPS of a smartphone if available. This works great unless the user is inside a building, which is where the less accurate WiFi based location is preferable. The main problem being that a GPS fix may never happen.

How should I request the accurate (GPS) location so that the less accurate location is returned if determining the accurate location takes too long?

Note that I really do need the GPS location if I can get it and can't use WiFi always.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that enableHighAccuracy does this already. [Geolaction High-Accuracy](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#high-accuracy)

> The user might also deny this capability, or the device might not be able to provide more accurate results than if the flag wasn't specified.

If that's not the case you could set a timeout if GPS is taking too long and call getCurrentPosition again with enableHighAccuracy set to false in the error callback(with a different error callback to avoid a loop).

```
    
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback, error_callback,{enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout: 50000});
        function error_callback(err){
            if(err.code==1){
             // user said no!
            }
            if(err.code==2){
             // position unavailable
            }
            if(err.code==3){
              // timeout
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback, different_error_callback,{enableHighAccuracy : false});
            }
        }
```